# How to sum 2 numbers in C language?

Tags: c

I am new to programming. I am learning how to sum in C language. Please see below code, What am I missing? Why its giving error?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 0;
    d = a + b + c;
    printf(d);
return 0;


}
```

Comment: Looks fine except for your `printf` statement.  Change it to `printf("%d\n", d);`

Comment: The `printf()` function needs a format string as the first argument, and zero or more extra arguments to provide values for conversion specifications started with `%`.

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and much more [about C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c), notably about [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). StackOverflow is not a *do-my-homework* service

Comment: Thank you sir it worked. What does "%d"  do in this case? I did some research and I found out that it tells C that the given input is "Integer". Is that true?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation of `printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). It probably is difficult for you, but it explains things

Comment: Sorry Basile Starynkevitch, I will delete this question now. Sorry for any inconvenience I have caused.

Comment: No problem, but before asking questions, read a bit of documentation (and perhaps cite what you have read). See also http://norvig.com/21-days.html for a useful insight about learning programming. Don't forget to enable all warnings in your compiler.

Comment: I recommend looking at a C tutorial.

Comment: Do not edit question code so as to invalidate existing answers  Rolled back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "f" in "printf" means "formatted".  The first parameter you pass to it has to be the format that you want to print with, not what you want to print.  In this case, it seems to me that you likely want to:

```
printf("%d\n", d);
```

The `%d` means that [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) should interpret the second parameter as a signed integer (which d actually is). The `\n` adds a newline (and usually flushes the buffer).

You can learn more about printf and its format by googling for it, or reading a man page about it, or its page in a compiler help file.

Answer (score 1):

you are printing a integer value. In order to print a integer value you have follow this way...

```
printf("%d",d);    // for integer it's %d
```

// so  your progam should looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 0;
    d = a + b + c;
    printf("%d\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation in English